# 301 Redirect - matching a portion of the filename

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, redirect

**[UPDATE]**

What I ask below just isn't possible. In which case, as my brain hurts, how can I simply redirect

*mydomain/folderA/folderB/name-0000.php*

to

*myNewDomain/folderC/folderB/name.php*

**[/UPDATE]**

I currently have some URL's which follow the pattern below.

***/folder/folder2/name-name-id.php***

The content has now been moved to a new domain with a different file structure. Redirecting them would be simple enough to do if it weren't for the fact that the ID portion of the URL is now different.

So I need to be able to redirect the following from domain A:

***/folderA/folderA2/name-name-0000.php***

to this on domain B:

***/folderB/folderB2/name-name-5555.php***

I can't figure out how to match the name portion and ignore the id. Note, the name could be n number of words long, it's not limited to two.

Any ideas?

Comment: How do you know what the new ID should be?

Comment: Having thought about it, you cant do what I'm after. As Jeremy points out I don't know the new ID so there is no way to know where to point it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regular expression for the URL path:

```
^/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+-[0-9]+\.php$
```

Now your mod_rewrite rule for the .htaccess file in your root directory can look like this to match the name and ID:

```
RewriteRule ^folderA/folderA2/([^/]+)-([0-9]+)\.php$ …
```

---

**Edit**    After you edited your requirements:

```
RewriteRule ^folderA/([^/]+)/([^/]+)-[0-9]+\.php$ /folderC/$1/$2.php [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think its possible without knowing the new ID.

Comment: Yes, works perfectly, thanks for the help and quick response.